# Word for "edited only for spelling, punctuation, grammar, and formatting"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to concisely convey that what's presented is not the author's exact original work, but has been edited with conservation of content, voice, and style in mind, changing only to e.g. fix misspellings, add a missing space after a period, capitalize the first letter of a sentence, remove manually-inserted newlines so the text can be reflowed, delete a duplicate sentence, split into paragraphs a text without any.

A short phrase would do too. The most important thing is that virtually everybody reading it interprets it as intended.

Close things I don't like:

- "conservatively edited": could be misinterpreted. Was an unimportant paragraph deleted? etc.
- "proofread" - proofreading technically means just marking mistakes, not correcting them, and doesn't really include things like reformatting for a new display medium.
- "edited for grammar": doesn't include all above classes of edits, and potentially includes edits specifically not made, like rephrasing technically-correct sentences.

Comment: Just [googling your question title](https://www.google.com/search?q=edit+spelling+punctuation+grammar+formatting) takes me to "proofreading", and from there googling for [its definition](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/proofread) gives an answer. That's one way to research. See also: _Proofreading_ vs _copyediting_ at https://nybookeditors.com/2016/05/whats-the-difference-between-copyediting-and-proofreading/

Comment: Proof reading is not editing - when a document is proof read, it is marked up to indicate errors, bu it is not edited.

Comment: You can say something like, 'this document has been lightly edited for clarity.' What you describe in the body of the post is what I would call light editing, but in the question you mention grammar. In my experience as an editor editing for grammar often means rewriting a sentence, which can lead to even deeper edits. It really depends upon the quality of the original writing, so it is possible to do light grammatical editing also.

Comment: @NVZ I did google it, "proofreading" doesn't work. But thank you for mentioning "copyediting", that might be right, I'll look into it a little more.

Comment: @UbuEnglish thanks for the suggestions. Maybe I was wrong to include "grammar", I never, for example, exchange a word for a synonym. The issue I have with "lightly edited" or "conservatively edited" is that one might interpret it incorrectly - was an unimportant paragraph deleted? etc.

Comment: @TristanBerger I wasn't posting an answer per se, but I was hinting on how to do some basic research since you didn't include any inside your question. Please include the research you have done and why those didn't help in the question body. :)

Comment: @NVZ done. I omitted it just to be concise, but I guess I misjudged the expectations here, I'll make a habit of including prior dead-ends. (I didn't actually delete your edit, I was typing when you made it and clobbered yours.)

Comment: @TristanBerger Good edits. The most commonly used reason for closing questions on this site is "Please include your research...".

Comment: I would probably just use something like "minor", like "I made some minor edits."

Comment: See also: "minor edits" as seen on SE https://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+minor+edits

Comment: @NVZ understood. I'd have appreciated if you led with that, instead of implying I'd done none. Reading both above links, I don't think "minor editing" is perfect, as e.g. not even unimportant phrases have been added/removed, and to somebody who hasn't researched it the term is vague. Copyediting, I think, is what I'm looking for, if you want to submit it as an answer.

Comment: @TristanBerger I see. My bad. If you wish to, you can self-answer. It's highly encouraged. I'm not writing one now. I've not written one in a long time either. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments on the question, ["copyediting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_editing) seems to be what I'm looking for. It includes "mechanical editing" (spelling, punctuation, capitalization, etc) as well as things like correcting inconsistencies, removing repetition, and imposing structure, "while respecting personal stylistic preferences [of the author]".

Copyediting could also include more drastic rewriting, which I don't intend, but it seems that *good* copyediting either avoids it or does it in a way somewhat-artfully consistent with the original work. It seems that the goal of copyediting is to do as I described.